# CSS for checked="checked" radio button not for only checked

Tags: html, css

I have one css to apply for checked radio button but not working when radio button is checked like checked="checked"

Comment: which code are you using? show the code..

Comment: There is a attribute for Radio button as **checked**. But if you using some styling you need to share the CSS.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
  background:red;
 }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r1" /> <label for="r1">radio</label>
```

Comment: @shankar   I want that css to be applied when the case is like

Comment: So what is your case

Comment: case is <input type="radio" name="r1"  checked="checked"/> not the       <input type="radio" name="r1" checked />